# wordpress my loadmore posts function returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

hey guys i have another wordpress question here i've looked at other posts but can't seem to find the solution. so figure ill post my code and see what happens. so im trying to load more posts with ajax but everytime i click it just returns a 0. any help would be much appreciated thanks!

functions.php

```
add_action( 'get_wp_ajax_publications', 'get_publications' );
add_action( 'get_wp_ajax_nopriv_publications', 'get_publications' );

function get_publications() {
if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'publications', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset' => 2 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
}
die();
}
```

myloadmore.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var offset_value = 0;
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
          'action' : 'get_publications',
          'offset' : offset_value
      },
      success:function(data) {
          $('#posts').html(data);
      }
  });
  console.log('loadmore clicked');
  offset_value +=2;
  return false;
  });

  });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is returning 0? Is the php returning 0?

Comment: @rjustin $('#posts').html(data);

Comment: What does console.log(data) say right before $('#posts').html(data)\

Comment: @rjustin it says 0

Comment: Try saving the html you want to send back in a variable $data = "<div>...."; then return $data; echoing is usually meant from when php is used as a preprocessor not a back end

Comment: @rjustin ok ok ill try that

Comment: @rjustin no luck still returning zero. ughhh!!! lol

Comment: Make sure your path is correct and the function is actually getting called on the server side. Its hard for me to debug without a working sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! had to change the names of my hooks

```
add_action( 'get_wp_ajax_publications', 'get_publications' );
add_action( 'get_wp_ajax_nopriv_publications', 'get_publications' );
```

should be

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_publications', 'get_publications' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_publications', 'get_publications' );
```

dropped the get_ from infront of my wp ajax call! thanks so much for your help @rjustin